# SHA512 hash with specified number of transformations

Tags: c#, sha512

I need to create SHA512 from string:

```
20191018143572123034102012221314181237774212
```

and it says, that I have to use 5000 transformations and hash result should be:

```
f8b915776eab735fdd10266b2e66068447904852b82c30eeb6de30703a087eb17ea4c4a37630494607194ddb9354c1211bd984fb5f4d9cff95f5a24ed52065e7
```

But my final hash string is:

```
B4CA157DBBC9DFC22A8046092C00367CBDB51F0D780A428CB7731251FA29D1E426E0853E0F52A1ACA8460D6D1679477509490D7F4305DCDC7D77FD0CC1993D3A
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sha512 = "";
    string puvodni = "20191018143572123034102012221314181237774212";
    Console.WriteLine("Puvodni: " + puvodni);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        sha512 = TestCrypt.ComputeSHA512(puvodni);
        Console.WriteLine("Hash: " + sha512);
        puvodni=sha512;
    }        
}

internal class TestCrypt
{
    public static string ComputeSHA512(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (SHA512 sha512 = SHA512.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashValue = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
            foreach (byte b in hashValue)
            {
                sb.Append($"{b:X2}");
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT

I am still in problems, update my program to this. Trying to use SHA512 built-in function, also BouncyCastle, but results are same.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    string puvodni = "20191018143572123034102012221314181237774212";
    Console.WriteLine("Puvodni: " + puvodni);

    //varianta 1
    SHA512 sha512 = SHA512.Create();
    byte[] hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(puvodni);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        hash=sha512.ComputeHash(hash);
        string result = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ". Hash: " + result);
    }

    //varianta 2
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(puvodni);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha512Digest digester = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha512Digest();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        byte[] retValue = new byte[digester.GetDigestSize()];
        digester.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        digester.DoFinal(retValue, 0);
        string result1 = BitConverter.ToString(retValue).Replace("-", "");
        Console.WriteLine("BouncyCastle Hash: " + i.ToString() + ". " + result1);
        bytes=retValue;
    }      
}
```

I need same result as on this page: https://www.podatki.gov.pl/kalkulator-sha-512
Where:
NIP: 1435721230
Numer konta: 34 1020 1222 1314 1812 3777 4212
Wprowadź datę: 18-10-2019

On one iteration result is ok, bud on second iteration I am receiving another hash string in my program.

Comment: You're taking a string, getting the UTF-8 bytes, hashing those, then taking the resulting bytes and turning them into a hex string, then starting again. First notice the asymmetry: you're taking the UTF-8 bytes that make up each character when going from string -> bytes, but turning each byte into 2 hex characters when going from bytes -> string. That said, you probably don't want to go via strings at all: just take the bytes which are output from one hash operation, and feed them directly into the next hash operation.